# Identify whether a website uses Flash content - From list of URLS

Tags: flash, web-crawler

I have been given a list of websites that need to be checked for any flash content. This could be flash video, flash ads, sIFR, FLV, FLA. I've been tasked with identifying whether flash content is being used on each site, and if so where. The list is a mixture of live and local sites.

I could do this manually, by going through every page on each site, but I'm sure there is a much more effective, time-saving and thorough way of doing this.

My first thought was to use a spider like Screaming Frog SEO spider, although I've not used it before. It has been mentioned this could flag areas of a site that are using flash by simply entering the site URL and crawling it. However I believe this would only work for sites that are live and not local ones.

The second thought would be to do a find search on terms like '.swf' and 'flash' in the local code repositories and note any files that refer to those terms. This would work locally but not live.

I think the eventual solution may be to use a combination of different techniques to ensure i've identified all the flash content.

My question is how would you guys go about doing this? All effective suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google's search parameters and a custom search term you can find the flash files that you need. 
e.g. -

```
site:domain-name.com filetype:swf
```

Google will return all the flash files that have been used on the domain. Not exactly what you need, but as close as possible in a single place.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @masmrdrr, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Search the source code of a particular webpage for ".swf" or simply right-click what we believe to be Flash content and see if a Flash context menu appears.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @EllaBarnes, but I'm hoping to find an automated solution as I need to search many sites as suggested in my first post.

Comment: Please don't push people to websites, especially your own where who knows what is captured or lurking. That is called spam